# How to change bottom hover

Tags: css

How to change bottom hover

```css
a.btn-listing,
button.btn-listing,
.navbar.navbar-site ul.navbar-nav > li.postadd > a.btn-listing,
#homepage a.btn-listing {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0071DC 0,#0071DC 100%);
}
```

so when I click to the bottom, the color changes?

Comment: i want when i click to the bottom, changing the color

Comment: How about adding the actual html as well since your current code snippet does nothing?

Comment: ```bottom``` or ```button```? How about: ```#homepage a.btn-listing:hover { /* hover styles */}```

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. The title and CSS are about hover but your description is about click. Which would you like? Also I assume you meant button not bottom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.